# RNCallKeep.addEventListener("answerCall") worked at the very first time after the app launch

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using this [react-native-callkeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-callkeep) to get call rings on iOS devices and it is working as expected. But getting one issue with its event listener `RNCallKeep.addEventListener("answerCall")`.

This listener is getting triggered only once after the app is launched. To trigger this listener I have to re-launch the app.

Comment: This happens if you reload the app. For me, if I kill the app and open it again, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

That work for me, just turn off debug, metro and relaunch.
Seem RNCallKeep not work addEventListener with debug. https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/issues/509#issuecomment-1002975654.